# Verbs ending in « oyer/uyer » vs. « eyer » vs. « ayer »

Tags: grammaire, verbes, conjugaison

Verbs with the following endings conjugate differently.

- Verbs with *-oyer/uyer* change "y" to "i" before silent "e" (*ennuyer* – *ennuie*).
- Verbs with *-eyer* do not change this way.
- Verbs with *-ayer* change "y" to "i" according to the writer's preference.

What is the reason for this? What does it signify or does this have any historic reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The orthography reflects the pronunciation.

One of the rule of French orthography is that if two sounds that would be written i occur next to each other, they're not written with ii, but rather with y. This can be either the vowel /i/ followed by the glide /j/ (as in  *fuyez*); or a digraph ending in i (oi, ai, ei) followed by the glide /j/ (as in *foyer*) or by the vowel /i/ (as in *pays*).

*Ennuyer* is pronounced (in my dialect, but the principle applies to Northern French French as well, just with different values for the vowels) /ɒ̃.nwi.je/. Notice how the letter y stands for both the vowel /i/ and the glide /j/?

*Ennuie* however is pronounced /ɒ̃.nwi:/. Here, there's only the vowel /i/ (elongated by the "mute" e, in Belgian, Swiss and eastern French French), without the glide, so the letter i is used.

This is also the case with, say, *choyer* (/ʃwa.je/) where two orthographic i would stand next to each other: the one of the digraph *oi* (for the sound /wa/) and the one for the glide /j/ . They fuse into y (i.e choi + ier = choyer rather than choiier). *Choie* is pronounced /ʃwa:/, so there's only one orthographic i, and no fusion into y.

With verbs in -eyer, the infinitive and the indicative present both have a digraph ending in i (ei pronounced /ɛ/) followed by /j/, so they're both written with the letter y. For example, *grasseyer* (/ɡʁa.sɛ.je/) et *grasseye* (/ɡʁa.sɛj/).

With verbs in -ayer, two pronunciations are accepted and thus two orthographies exist. The verb *payer* (pai + ier = /pɛ.je/) in the indicative present can be pronounced either /pe:/ and written paie or pronounced /pɛj/ and written paye. (In Parisian French this would be /pe/ and /pej/, with the same effects on orthography)

Comment: Note: When followed by an *i*, the first semi-vowel is generally /ɥ/ rather than /w/. The standard phonetic transcription of *ennuyer* is /ɒ̃.nɥi.je/.

Comment: The analysis would be easier for me to understand with the syllables written choi.yer and pai.yer rather than choi + ier and pai + ier which misled me to seek two morphemes instead of two syllables...